# GeoJSONLayer make callback status load javascript api arcgis

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I want to show response when GeoJSONLayer(dataLayer) status callback success/error loaded. I tried many times but still not show. Can anyone give me sample callback when GeoJSONLayer success/failed loaded, because I want disable enable button status when button on click.

```
var geojsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
    url             : "<?php echo $url_data_service;?>",
    copyright       : "PEMKAB BOGOR",
    popupTemplate   : {
        title       : "No Register : {no_register}",
        content     : '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"><tr><td>Nama Pemohon</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{nama_pemohon}</td></tr><tr><td>Organisasi Pemohon</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{nama_organisasi}</td></tr><tr><td>Foto</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td><img class="img-responsive" src="{image_source}"></td></tr><tr><td>Kecamatan</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{kecamatan}</td></tr><tr><td>Kelurahan</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{kelurahan}</td></tr></table><a style="color:white; font-weight:bold;" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" href="{permalink}">Lihat Detail</a>'
    },
    renderer        : {
        type    : "simple",
        field   : "no_register",
        symbol  : {
            type        : "simple-line",
            color       : [4, 90, 141],
            width       : 1,
            cap         : "round",
            join        : "round"
        }
    }
});

var map = new Map({
    basemap : "gray",
    layers  : [geojsonLayer]
});

var view = new MapView({
    container   : "ArcGIS",
    center      : [ 106.824651,-6.479687 ],
    zoom        : 12,
    map         : map
});

view.ui.add(
    new Expand({
        view        : view,
        content     : new BasemapGallery({view : view, container : document.createElement("div")
    })
}), "top-left");


$('.btnload').click(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('data-href');
    $(this).prop('disabled','disabled');
    let dataLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
        url             : "<?php echo $url_data_service;?>/" + page,
        loadStatus      : false,
        copyright       : "PEMKAB BOGOR",
        popupTemplate   : {
            title       : "No Register : {no_register}",
            content     : '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"><tr><td>Nama Pemohon</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{nama_pemohon}</td></tr><tr><td>Organisasi Pemohon</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{nama_organisasi}</td></tr><tr><td>Foto</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td><img class="img-responsive" src="{image_source}"></td></tr><tr><td>Kecamatan</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{kecamatan}</td></tr><tr><td>Kelurahan</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{kelurahan}</td></tr></table><a style="color:white; font-weight:bold;" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" href="{permalink}">Lihat Detail</a>'
        },
        renderer        : {
            type    : "simple",
            field   : "no_register",
            symbol  : {
                type        : "simple-line",
                color       : [4, 90, 141],
                width       : 2,
                cap         : "round",
                join        : "round"
            }
        }
    });
    view.map.add(dataLayer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`when()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GeoJSONLayer.html#when) method

```
$('.btnload').click(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('data-href');
    $(this).prop('disabled','disabled');
    let dataLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
        url             : "<?php echo $url_data_service;?>/" + page,
        loadStatus      : false,
        copyright       : "PEMKAB BOGOR",
        popupTemplate   : {
            title       : "No Register : {no_register}",
            content     : '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"><tr><td>Nama Pemohon</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{nama_pemohon}</td></tr><tr><td>Organisasi Pemohon</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{nama_organisasi}</td></tr><tr><td>Foto</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td><img class="img-responsive" src="{image_source}"></td></tr><tr><td>Kecamatan</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{kecamatan}</td></tr><tr><td>Kelurahan</td><td style="width:5px;">:</td><td>{kelurahan}</td></tr></table><a style="color:white; font-weight:bold;" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" href="{permalink}">Lihat Detail</a>'
        },
        renderer        : {
            type    : "simple",
            field   : "no_register",
            symbol  : {
                type        : "simple-line",
                color       : [4, 90, 141],
                width       : 2,
                cap         : "round",
                join        : "round"
            }
        }
    });

    dataLayer.when(function() {
        //success
        $('.btnload').prop('disabled', '');
    }, function() {
        //error
        $('.btnload').prop('disabled', '');
    });

    view.map.add(dataLayer);
});
```